# When logging in using Facebook, the redux store is not updating for my react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm building a react-native app using Facebook login via Firebase and storing the credentials in my redux state.  On my login page, I have a button that triggers a check to see if the person is already logged in.  If they are, it goes straight to the "Dashboard" (via react-navigation) and if the person is not logged in, it opens up the Facebook flow.

The issue I'm having is that, after going through the Facebook flow, nothing happens.  However, when I click on the "Login" button one more time, then it does successfully load the person and do the redirect.  Any idea what could be going on here?  I have a feeling I'm not using my async/await properly, but can't seem to figure it out.  Below is my code for the relevant parts.

## part of /screens/Login.js

```
  logUserIn = async (loadUser, setLoggedInUser) => {
    await loadCurrentUser(loadUser);
    console.log(this.props.user.name);
    if (Boolean(this.props.user.name)) {
      await setLoggedInUser(true);
    } else {
      loginWithFacebook()
      .then(loadCurrentUser(loadUser));
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    const {
      loadUser,
      user,
      isLoggedIn,
      setLoggedInUser,
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Button
          title='Login'
          onPress={ () => this.logUserIn(loadUser, setLoggedInUser) }
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## /services/facebookAPI.js

```
export const loadCurrentUser = async (loadUser) => {
  const user = await userLoginStatus();
  console.log('pre-if: ' + Boolean(await user));
  if (Boolean(user)) {
    console.log('post-if: ' + Boolean(user));
    console.log(user.displayName + ' is logged in!');
    loadUser(user);
  } else {
    console.log('user not logged in');
    return null;
  }
};
```

## /actions/actions.js

```
export const setLoggedInUser = (isLoggedIn) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'LOGGED_IN',
    isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
  });
  dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Dashboard' }));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try going the listener route. Basically, in your root component, you have three states. Loading, logged out, or logged in. Loading is the initial state, and then you check to see if the result of `onAuthStateChanged` includes the user. If so, then you're logged in and you can load the logged in views. If not, you can load your signed out view (which in your case is facebook login).

```
componentWillMount () {
  this.unsubscriber = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      // Do your login!
    } else {
      // Do your logged out stuff!
    }
  )}


// Don't forget to unsubscribe:
componentWillUnmount () {
  if (this.unsubscriber) {
    this.unsubscriber()
  }
}
```

The reason this is nice is that firebase calls your callback here as soon as the auth state changes. So as soon as they login with facebook, this will fire and you will know that you're ready to start handling login stuff.

Comment: I've actually gone ahead and implemented this on the logout.  i.e. I set the listener on the main "dashboard" page and when I logout (it's done via a modal) the listener automatically changes the "isLoggedIn" flag and then routes back to the Login flag.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, this turned out to be the way to go on the login as well.  I created a listener to look for user changes on the login and make a redirect to the dashboard.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing async/await, which only should be used for async code. Also, mixing async/await with Promise.then() is perfectly possible but it's best avoided and definitely within the same method I wouldn't recommend it.

Also, you in your success path you are again referring to props.loadUser, which of course has not changed since the first time you called it. The second time you press the button props.user did change and that is why you end up in the happy path.

```
  logUserIn = async (loadUser, setLoggedInUser) => {

    await loadCurrentUser(loadUser);

    if (Boolean(this.props.user.name)) {
      setLoggedInUser(true); // await not needed, dispatching is synchronous
    } else {
      await loginWithFacebook(); // refactored to await for consistency reasons
      setLoggedInUser(true); // you are logged in at this point
    }
  };
```

You might also need to add the loadUser() method above setLogginInUser(), but since you did not add that function I don't know what it's used for.